# Does querydsl suffers of the same limitations as JPA Criteria API?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, querydsl, or-mapper

JPA Criteria API has some important limitations. For example:

- no support for right-outer-join
- support for left-outer-join only if the relation in the entities is in the same direction
- no support for subquery neither in SELECT nor in FROM clauses

Does QueryDsl `querydsl-jpa` suffer from the same limitations?

What about QueryDsl `querydsl-sql`?

EDIT:
From the QueryDsl documentation (no concrete experience with it), QueryDsl provides two query-classes `JPAQuery` and `JPASQLQuery`. The first seems to have the same limitation as JPA Criteria API, but `JPASQLQuery` doesn't seem. If I find time, I will dive deeper into code and try it. But if someone already knows something about it, then you are welcome!

Comment: The Criteria API makes me want to cry every time I see it. I'd use QueryDSL every time regardless of any limitations it may have (not that I'm saying there are any).

Comment: Interesting. Please fell free to add argumentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assumption is correct. Querydsl JPA has the same restrictions as the mentioned three restrictions are also restrictions of JPQL, the query language of JPA.

`JPAQuery` is for JPQL queries and `JPASQLQuery` is for JPA native (SQL) queries.

Comment: Thank you Timo Westkämper! Just to clarify: `JPAQuery` has the same limitations as JPQL but `JPASQLQuery` don't. Is that correct? (I get confused with the name "Querydsl JPA": does it represent `JPAQuery` only, or `JPAQuery` and `JPASQLQuery` together.

Comment: You are correct. Querydsl JPA is Querydsl integration for the JPA API queries, JPQL (JPAQuery) and SQL (JPASQLQuery).